# Oracle Apex Execution of Page Process

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I Created the tabular form with two page process. i am in need to execute the first page process for created and modified rows and second page process need to executed only once.

how do i achieve this functionality

Thanks & Regards,
Priya

Answer (score 1):

The is no inbuilt way, you would need to code something. For the Process to run only once create a hidden field, set it to one the first time the process to run and have this Process only run when the hidden field is 0.

The Process for Edit and Create should only be triggered when the Create/Edit buttons are run. You can have triggers for this in Apex. Look at the Conditions dropdown, select Request when Request is the name of the Submit button (e.g edit or add)